# Targeting API 28 on delphi

Tags: delphi, android-api-levels

I have a problem trying to publish my APK to the Google Play store. It says I must update my API level at 28. The application uses a maps service, so it must have the Internet and GPS permissions.

Does anyone know how to update the API level on Delphi?

Comment: Delphi 10.3.2 already sets the target API level (targetSdkVersion) to 28. Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: I use Delphi 10.2 Tokyo. Does this mean I can no longer create apps for Google Play, since this version of delphi (from what I can tell) only supports API level 14? OR is there is way to circumvent this major constraint? I tried adjusting the Manifest XML file, but Delphi recreates it and puts max API level 14 in it. Perhaps there is way to change this behavior? Does anyone know how to?

Answer (score 2):

Simply [customize your project's `AndroidManifest.xml` file](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Preparing_an_Android_Application_for_Deployment#Customizing_Your_AndroidManifest.xml_File) to set the `<uses-sdk>` element's `minSdkVersion`, `maxSdkVersion`, and `targetSdkVersion` values as needed.

Comment: Done, but now google play says that my APK must be 64-bit and not 32-bit. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Arnau Embarcadero has not [released an Android 64bit compiler yet](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/august-2019-delphi-android-beta-plans-august-roadmap-update). You need to [request an extension from Google](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/google-play-store-android-32-bit-extension-for-delphi-and-c-builder-customers) ([additional information](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/additional-information-for-the-android-32-bit-extension)) to continue posting 32bit **app updates** (not **new apps**) through Aug 2020.

Comment: Once I adjusted the manifest file, how do I get it to Google? I last uploaded apps here in 2014. Much has changed since...

Comment: @HendrikPotgieter Read Embarcadero's documentation on [Android Mobile Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Android_Mobile_Application_Development), particularly the section on [Submitting Your Android App to Google Play](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Submitting_Your_Android_App_to_Google_Play)